# Configure Jenkins Backup Plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, backup, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

I've encountered a problem using the backup plugin.
I'm getting an error when trying to restore a previous backup using the backup plugin.
"Error copying backup files: Failed setLastModified on /var/lib/jenkins_restore.
I ran "chmod -R 777 /var/lib" to solve a previous problem which that was the only solution.
Would appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you recursively chmod?

Comment: I did, thanks for clearing it out. I edited the post.